# Weird behaviour of HttpURLConnection

Tags: android

I have a very simple method to get InputStream from url:

```
private InputStream request(String uri) {
    Log.d(TAG, "initialize request: "+uri);
    try {
        URL url = new URL(uri));
        Log.d(TAG, "initialize req: "+url);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        Log.d(TAG, "initialize open conn");
        if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            Log.d(TAG, "initialize return is");
            return connection.getInputStream();
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "initialize: fail");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "initialize: what happened?");
    return null;
}
```

and it used to work perfect. But now, when I'm trying to use it, for some reason it stops on 'connection.getResponseCode()'. Just stops, nothing else happens. The logs looks like this:

> tag: initialize req: http://uri.provided.to.method
>
> tag: initialize open conn

And that's it. It literally stops there and doesn't print or return anything else. Same effect for 'connection.getResponseMessage()'. Any ideas why it happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Does this still happen if you call set `setConnectTimeout` and `setReadTimeout` with a small non-zero value (e.g. 200) before `getResponseCode`? (note: I'm not suggesting this as a solution, just as a means of trying to find out what the problem might be).

Comment: @Michael It results in a timeout exception, which is caught in a 'catch' block.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, problem solved. Apparently connection was made too early, before the url was ready.